# Using Proximity API

Tags: google-beacon-platform

I purchased an Eddystone beacon from RadiusNetworks. I am trying to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/register) tutorial to register my beacon. But, I keep getting 401 auth error. Is there another step-by-step tutorial on proximity api?

Attaching Postman screenshot
[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to show an example request/response (e.g. using curl) demonstrating the failure.  You can redact your credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to generate and pass in an OAuth token with your request. See https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/how-tos/authorizing for information on this.

In short though you need to add the Proximity API to your developer console, generate an OAuth credential and then use that to generate a token. How you do this differs a lot on your language of choice.

Finally once you have the token you need to pass it in with your request. This can be done using access_token parameter on the querystring or using the "Bearer" HTTP request header.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Are there any instructions that describe how Postman can be used to call Google Beacon Proximity APIs?

Comment: I just installed Postman to take a look at you should be able to do the following. I did this quickly and had problems since I'm running 2 Chromes and you can only make one default but it should work or get you very close.  
- In Authorizaiton tab choose OAuth2  
- Auth URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth  
- Token URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token  
- Client ID/secret. Get these from Google Developer Console  
- Scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userlocation.beacon.registry  

Don't forget to add the Postman callback URL to the redirect URL in the console

Comment: Credentials->Add credentials->OAuth2.0 client ID->select Chrome App radio button (since I am using Postman)->enter last part of Postman's Chrome Web store URL->hit create button
These steps will only generate a client ID, not a secret..am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your def in the wrong place. I don't use Postman day to day I suggest to create a new question asking how to generate an OAuth2 token for Google.  It's not specific to the Proximity API but to almost all Google APIs so someone will have an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

I might be late but it is for people who might need help in future.

1. You need to create a project or use already created one at
   https://console.developers.google.com
2. Go to dashboard, click Enable APIS and Services and enable Google
   proximity API
3. Then go to credentials create credentials (I am assuming you will
   need it for web) Create credentials - > Create API Key (It can be
   unrestricted no issue). Once Created then again Create credentials->OAuth client ID (Create it for Web Application).

   Once you have both OAUTH and API key open Postman to test.
4. In postman after putting the url you are testing, go to
   authentication tab of postman  Change type to OAuth 2.0 Add
   authorization data to - > Request Headers Get Access Token Token
   Name:Token Name

   Grant Type:Authorization Code

   CallbackURL:https://developers.google.com/oauth2callback

   AuthURL:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

   Access TokenURL:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

   ClientID:Your OAuth client ID

   Client Secret: OAuth client Secret

   Scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userlocation.beacon.registry

   Client Authentication:Send as basic auth header and you are done i
   hope it helps :)